# How to get the size of the values in a Map?

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary, hashtable

I have a collection which I load at the beginning of a program and I give for granted that the String array that I use as value will have always the same length, for all the entries, plus that it will at least contain 1 value.
From these entries, I need to get the size of the array I've used. As of now, I'm doing it like so:

```
Map<String, String[]> people = new HashTable<>();
people.put("miao", new String[]{"bau","cip","muu"});
people.values().iterator().next().length; //returns 3
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: That's good enough, unless you can obtain that length before you put the first array value in the Map.

Comment: Should I delete the question? Is it badly formatted or something? I'm having terrible difficulties on this website in understanding the voting...

Comment: You should probably use a `HashMap` rather than a Hashtable (note little-'t').  `Hashtable` is synchronized.  `HashMap` is not and is usually what you want (to avoid the cost of synchronization).  For most purposes `Hashtable` is old news.  Have you considered using a `List<String>` instead of a `String[]`.  Again, this is usually preferred.  For most purposes you should think of arrays as a legacy (or optimization) feature of Java.

Comment: @Paul About the sync thing, I may actually need it, so that is why I'm using it. As per the List... Well I didn't think about it. Do you have a read about your last sentence? Isn't a List a little much of a wrapper to store a simply splitted string?

Comment: @Vale It's just one down-vote, nothing to worry about (unless the down-voter bothers to give a good reason for the down-vote).

Comment: @Vale Re `List` versus arrays: it is a low-level / high-level thing.  Arrays are pretty low-level, lacking in utility (can't easily append, etc), can't be immutable, don't play well in many cases with generics/lambdas etc.  For synchronization you might be better off with `Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String,List<String>>())`.  This at least makes it clear that you are deliberately depending on synchronization capabilities, and not just being old-school with your collections.  I think there is a tendency to view code using `Hashtable` (and `Vector`) as likely being legacy code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @Eran (in the comments) I have already answered my own question *in the question*, so, to get the size of the Value (if it is an array) do:

```
Map<String, String[]> people = new HashTable<>();
people.put("miao", new String[]{"bau","cip","muu"});
people.values().iterator().next().length; //returns 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of Guava's [ListMultimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html):

```
ListMultimap<String, String> people = ArrayListMultimap.create();
people.putAll("miao", new ArrayList("bau","cip","muu");

people.get("miao").size();//returns 3
```

Comment: thank you Tom; I should have specified that I can't be sure what the keys will be.